# ¿Dónde debería ubicar clausula WHERE junto con GROUP_CONCAT y EXTRACT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo cuatro tablas: *usuarios*, *faltas*, *pases* y *omisiones*.

Estructura y datos de ejemplo de la tabla *usuarios*:

| id | no_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1120 | María |
| 04 | 1121 | José |
| 05 | 1134 | Meli |

Estructura y datos de ejemplo de la tabla *faltas*:

| id | no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01/08/21 |
| 02 | 1104 | 03/08/21 |
| 03 | 1104 | 04/08/21 |
| 04 | 1104 | 05/08/21 |

Estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *pases*:

| id | no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 02/08/21 |
| 02 | 1120 | 02/08/21 |
| 03 | 1120 | 04/08/21 |

Estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *omisiones*:

| id | no_empleado | fecha | estatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 02/08/21 | ENTRADA |
| 02 | 1120 | 02/08/21 | SALIDA |
| 03 | 1120 | 04/08/21 | ENTRADA |

Busco obtener un resultado como este:

| no_empleado | nombre | pases | faltas | entrada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | Juan | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1104 | Luis | null | 3,4,5 | null |
| 1120 | María | 2,4 | null | 4 |

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL que busco adaptar:

```
(SELECT u.no_empleado, u.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM o.fecha)) AS 'entrada' FROM usuarios u RIGHT JOIN pases p ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado LEFT JOIN faltas f ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado LEFT JOIN omisiones o ON u.no_empleado = o.no_empleado GROUP BY u.no_empleado)UNION(SELECT u.no_empleado, u.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM o.fecha)) AS 'entrada' FROM usuarios u RIGHT JOIN faltas f ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado LEFT JOIN pases p ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado LEFT JOIN omisiones o ON u.no_empleado = o.no_empleado GROUP BY u.no_empleado)UNION(SELECT u.no_empleado,u.nombre,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.fecha)) AS 'pases',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM f.fecha)) AS 'faltas', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM o.fecha)) FROM usuarios u RIGHT JOIN omisiones o ON u.no_empleado = o.no_empleado LEFT JOIN faltas f ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado LEFT JOIN pases p ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado GROUP BY u.no_empleado)
```

Lo único que quiero es que en la columna *entrada* se desplieguen exclusivamente los campos en donde *estatus* es igual a *ENTRADA*. Actualmente con el *query* que tengo me despliega indistintamente todos los campos de la columna *estatus*. Cabe rescatar que en la tabla resultado sólo despliego el día de la fecha almacenada (sin el mes y año).

De antemano, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo modificaría la consulta para evitar la `UNION` entre subconsultas y el uso de `DISTINCT` ("Es tentador el uso de SELECT DISTINCT para eliminar filas duplicadas en los usos de JOIN. Es mucho mejor determinar que filas son las duplicadas y arreglar el problema").

Lo que puedes hacer es vincular con subconsultas en lugar de con las tablas (faltas, pases  y omisiones) que te devulvan el no_empleado y la cadena con los días (agrupando en cada una por no_empleado). En la tabla omisiones agregarías la claúsula `WHERE` para restringir solo las entradas.

Es verdad que si tenés el mismo día en distinto mes, y no quieres que se repitan en el resultado deberás agregar el `DISTINCT` (pero de esta forma estarás evitando la duplicación de filas que producen los múltiples `JOINs`).

No he podido probar la query, por lo que quizas haya que hacer alguna correción.

```
SELECT u.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       p.dias AS pases,
       f.dias AS faltas, 
       o.dias AS entrada 

FROM usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS dias FROM faltas GROUP BY no_empleado) f ON u.no_empleado = f.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS dias FROM pases GROUP BY no_empleado) p ON u.no_empleado = p.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS dias FROM omisiones WHERE estatus = 'ENTRADA' GROUP BY no_empleado) o ON u.no_empleado = o.no_empleado;
```

Si quieres omitir los usuarios que no tienen pases, faltas y entradas lo puedes hacer agregando la siguiente cláusula `WHERE`:

```
WHERE f.no_empleado IS NOT NULL OR p.no_empleado IS NOT NULL OR o.no_empleado IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Excelente, es exacto lo que buscaba y no hizo falta modificar tu consulta. Una duda más que aunque lo puse en la tabla, olvidé mencionar textualmente: ¿Cómo podría ordenar los días ascendentemente?

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido util mi query. En la función [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) puedes agregar la cláusula `ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha) ASC` .